# Query builder more than one column Increment

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to update user account detail by increment to their All_balance, Available_balance,Credit Laravel 5.8 Query builder

**Worked with one column**

```
    $account = DB::table('accounts')
                            ->where(['user_id'=>$userId])
                            ->increment('all_balance',$amount);
```

**I tried this below but not working**

```
     $account = DB::table('accounts')
                            ->where(['user_id'=>$userId])
                            ->increment(function($increment){
                                $increment->('all_balance',$amount);
                                $increment->('available_balance',$amount);
                                $increment->('credit',$amount);
                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this...**

```
 $account = DB::table('accounts')
                            ->where(['user_id'=>$userId])
                            ->update([
                                'all_balance' => DB::raw('all_balance+$amount'),
                                'available_balance' =>DB::raw('available_balance+$amount'),
                                'credit' => DB::raw('credit+$amount'),
                              ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zar NI Ko Ko i appreciate your response because it realy do helped me but just that it gave me error as a result of no concatenation between the column names and the variable name($amount) so it was seeing the variable as another column. Everything is fine now

**Working Code**

```
    $account = DB::table('accounts')
            ->where(['user_id'=>$userId])
            ->update([
                'all_balance' => DB::raw('all_balance + '.$amount.''),
                'available_balance' =>DB::raw('available_balance + '.$amount.''),
                'credit' => DB::raw('credit + '.$amount.''),
              ]);
```